# How to execute git command from build.gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

Could you guys clarify why

```
def getBuildSuffix() {
  return 'git rev-list HEAD | wc -l | tr -d " "'.execute().text.trim()
}
```

returns nothing to me taking into consideration there is data when you run git command from a command line:

```
prototype (master) $ git rev-list HEAD | wc -l | tr -d " "
72
```

May be I'm just executing a git command from my `build.gradle` in a wrong way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Pipe is a shell feature so you need to go like:

```
['sh', '-c', 'git rev-list HEAD | wc -l | tr -d " "'].execute().text.trim()
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to do your own piping or call by shell (see answer from @topr).  see the error:

```
def p1 = 'git rev-list HEAD | wc -l | tr -d " "'.execute()
p1.waitFor()
println p1.exitValue()
//-> 128
println p1.errorStream.text
//-> fatal: ambiguous argument '|': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
//-> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
//-> 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
println p1.text 
//-> nothing
```

Use groovy e.g.:

```
println 'git rev-list HEAD'.execute().text.split().size()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this for Android you need `Integer.parseInt()`, like so:

`Integer.parseInt(['sh','-c','git rev-list --all --count']
.execute().text.trim())`