# Android Studio Best way import module from other repository

Tags: android, git, gradle, repository

I have to import a project from a Github repository as a module inside an Android Studio project that it committed into another repository.

The project I have to import from Github will be updated constantly so it means that I'll have to refresh every now and again for having the latest changes done on the module.

Since the new module as the base project will have independent development, which is the best way to import the module? should I check out the Github repository inside the Android Studio folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd advice to use [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/)

Jitpack: Easy to use package repository for GitHub, just include it inside your gradle, and now you can deal with github project as a module

Thanks Jitpack <3

---

For example:
we have this repository: https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager

and with Jitpack in your gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

---

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.florent37:MaterialViewPager:1.0.5'
}
```

---

And you can use it with private repositories, but it require signup/login

Comment: I need to keep multiple modules in separate git repos, can i use jitpack to merge my modules under a single android studio project and then easily push the changes back using github client or gradle etc.?

Comment: Is Jitpack support private repositories which are hosted on bitbucket.org as bitbucket is also run on Git protocol.

Answer (score 4):

1. Clone you git repository into local folder.
2. In Android Studio choose File -> Import Module and choose cloned directory project.
3. If Android Studio do not detect VCS root go to the Settings->Version Control and setup your directory.

When you need update project just use a stadard IDE pull options(VCS->Update Project(Ctrl+T)).

*I use stash options before pulling.*

Comment: Does that allow you to make changes in that particular module'slocal repository so you can push them back without copy pasting the modified code back into the local repo folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout the github repository in your Project folder for Android Studio to read.

And you'll have to keep it up-to-date.

You can run Git commands from a Gradle rule like so:

```
['sh', '-c', 'cd mymodule && git pull origin master && cd -'].execute()
```

(Just an example - credits to [How to execute git command from build.gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26633310/603270))